# Sonar throwing error BadDatabaseVersion

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed sonar and mysql database on server A and on server B. I'm trying to run sonar analysis using sonar-runner but every time I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:130)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: The current batch process and the configured remote server do not share the same DB configuration.
    - Batch side: jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true (sonar / *****)
    - Server side: check the configuration at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/system
```

Server B is accessing DB from server A. I have checked all configurations from batch and server side everything seems to be ok.

I also googled and found the [following link](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3685),
but I cannot understand what to do for resolving this issue.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6):

This error can also happen if you have **2 Sonar instances pointing at the same database**.  You can only have one Sonar instance per database.

Sonar updates a row in the `properties` table where `prop_key = 'sonar.core.id'` every time it starts up, and then compares the cached value against the one in the database whenever an analysis is executed.  If the two don't match then you get the error.

To fix it, shut down both instances then only restart the instance you want to keep. Sonar will reset the sonar.core.id value and things should work again.

You can get the server's cached id via REST: 
`http://server:port/sonar/api/server`

It has to match the one in the database for Sonar to work. 
`select * from properties where prop_key = 'sonar.core.id'`

Comment: For some reason http://server:port/sonar/api/server and http://server:port/api/server give two different responses.  Looking at the debug, the batch processing was checking the later and comparing it to the database value.

Comment: Pretty interesting mail chain on a similar limes giving some more insights - http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/How-to-scale-Sonar-Unable-to-run-two-instance-on-the-same-DB-tc5002091.html#none  However its still open.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the database settings used by the Sonar server:

- http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/system

Match the database credentials used by your build?

The error message suggests they don't. The JIRA issue [SONAR-3685](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3685) was closed with a "Not A Bug" resolution code.

Comment: hello everything seems to be ok!!!   I am really confused what to do???  please if could someone help me

Comment: Check the "System Info" screen. You're certain that the Database URL, Login, Driver and Driver Class fields match the setup of your Sonar runner? If that is the case, capture a screenshot of your Sonar screen and attach a copy of the Sonar runner property file and reopen the JIRA issue. Apologies, without more information this issue does appear to be a misconfiguration.