# Running Two Sonar Instances with One DB

Tags: sonarqube

As per this question: [Sonar throwing error BadDatabaseVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339315/sonar-throwing-error-baddatabaseversion) it is not possible to run two sonar instances using the same database. Everything I've read so far implies the only solution is to shut down both instances and only restart the one you want to keep. Is my only other option to run two sonar instances, to have another sonar database? This seems pretty costly, and it seems that the only thing holding back sonar from running another instance is sharing server.core.id

So I guess I have two questions:
  1) Why is sonar built with this dependency?
  2) Are there any other options to run two instances on the same db?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://www.rubyrep.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, SonarQube currently can't have 2 servers started on the same DB. This limitation (that is referenced in [this JIRA ticket](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1568)) has beeen here by design since the very beginning - to make sure that you can't start 2 servers having a different set of plugins but pointing to the same DB.

To answer your second question, there's no way to have 2 instances pointing to the same DB. But we've starting a big refactoring to eventually make it possible to have a cluster of SonarQube instances, so feel free to watch the [SONAR-5391](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5391) ticket and vote for it.

Comment: any update after 9 years?